# Android ListView losing background color when scrolled

Tags: java, android, listview, colors, background

I am changing the background color of the clicked item

```
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_create_msg, container, false);

     final EditText tbsendto=(EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.tbsendto);

     System.out.println("Aqui");

    SharedPreferences userDetails = getActivity().getBaseContext().getSharedPreferences("Login", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    username=userDetails.getString("Unm","");


    GetUsersMsg getMsg=new GetUsersMsg(getActivity());
    getMsg.execute("new",username);
    final ListView list=(ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.lv_users_new_msg);

    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View itemview, int i, long l) {
         View v=itemview;
            v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_create_msg,null);

            final String item = ((TextView) itemview).getText().toString();

            System.out.println(item);
            String textsendto;
            System.out.println(tbsendto.getText().toString());
            if (tbsendto.getText().toString().contains(item)){
                textsendto=tbsendto.getText().toString().replace( "  " + item,"");
                itemview.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#19394a"));
                ((TextView) itemview).setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

            }else {
                textsendto=tbsendto.getText().toString() + "  " +  item;
                itemview.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                ((TextView) itemview).setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#19394a"));
            }


            tbsendto.setText(textsendto);
            tbsendto.setSelection(tbsendto.getText().length());

        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

But when i scroll the listview and the item leaves the screen is loosing the given color.
[Selecting items in the listivew](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yN7F.png)

[Sctrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2jOf.png)

What am i doing wrong and why is it loosing the given color?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Because when scrolling the views are recreated. You have to set the color in your adapter.

Comment: Could you please tell me how would that be?